# Cannot coerce column to be the same date time type in R

Tags: r, datetime, posix, lubridate, posixct

```
> class(report_df$LASTACTIVITYDATE)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Because there are the mixed data types of POSIXct and POSIXt I cannot process my data correctly.
Issue is happening in lubridate.

When I try either of the following it does not help:

```
library(lubridate)

report_df$LASTACTIVITYDATE <- as.POSIXct(report_df$LASTACTIVITYDATE)

report_df <- report_df %>% mutate(LASTACTIVITYDATE = mdy_hms(LASTACTIVITYDATE))
```

Sometimes it just changes the whole column to NA.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is *both* POSIXct *and* POSIXt. POSIXt is a kind of parent class for both POSIXct and POSIXlt.

From the documentation:

> "POSIXct" is more convenient for including in data frames, and "POSIXlt" is closer to human-readable forms. A virtual class [(see note 1)] "POSIXt" inherits from both of the classes: it is used to allow operations such as subtraction to mix the two classes. ([source](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html))

As to why your attempts didn't seem to work:

- using `as.POSIXct()` wouldn't have done anything, as the data was already POSIXct format
- `mdy_hms()` parses strings, not POSIXct objects. Any ones it cannot parse it will return NA for.

Notes:

1. "Classes exist for which there are no actual objects, the virtual classes, in fact a very important programming tool. They are used to group together ordinary classes that want to share some programming behavior, without necessarily restricting how the behavior is implemented. Virtual class definitions may if you want include slots (to provide some common behavior without fully defining the object—see traceable-class for an example)." ([source](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/methods/html/Classes.html))